# Batching Stored Procedure Commands in EF 4.2

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, batching, entity-framework-4.2

I've got a call to a stored procedure, that is basically an INSERT stored procedure. It inserts into Table A, then into Table B with the identity from Table A.

Now, i need to call this stored procedure N amount of times from my application code.

Is there any way i can batch this? At the moment it's doing N round trips to the DB, i would like it to be one.

The only approach i can think of is to pass a the entire list of items across the wire, via an User Defined Table Type.

But the problem with this approach is that i will need a CURSOR in the sproc to loop through each item in order to do the insert (because of the identity field).

Basically, can we batch `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` with EF 4.2?

Or can we do it with something like Dapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep it like that and in the stored procedure just do a [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) between your target table and the table parameter. Because you are always coming with new records, the `MERGE` will enter only on the `INSERT` branch.

In this case, using `MERGE` like this is an easy way of doing batch inserts without a cursor.

Also, another way which also avoids the use of a cursor is to use a `INSERT from SELECT` statement in the SP.

Comment: i cant do this, because of the IDENTITY field required from each insert into table A. the stored proc needs to do 2 inserts, table A (which gets the identity), then table b (with the new identity). i could insert a bunch of records into table a with a merge (or insert from select) no problem, but how do i get the records into table b with the identity? i cant, unless i join on another field (which isn't unique, and hence that wont work either)

Comment: @RPM1984: What about using the `OUTPUT` statement for the `MERGE` in table A and then use it for inserting in table B? `OUTPUT` can give you the identity column + any other column you may want in a temp table or in a table variable and you can use it to insert in B. This applies if I'm not missing anything about the relations between A and B.

Comment: Docs and samples for `OUTPUT` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: ahh now your onto something...will try this out and get back to you.